# java.util.regex.Pattern matcher causes high CPU usage

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

We are having issue with a regex validation using Pattern. It is happening in Spring framework and hibernate's validation.

Below snippet shows the request object being validated:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity create(@RequestBody RequestObj request) {
  validationService.validate(request);
  .....

}
```

Regex pattern:

```
public class RequestObj {

  @Pattern(regexp = "^([a-zA-Z])+[-.'\\s]?[-a-zA-Z]*$", message = ValidationConstant.ERR_INVALID_FIRST_NAME)
  @NotNull(message = ValidationConstant.ERR_FIRST_NAME_EMPTY)
  @Size(max = 30, message = ValidationConstant.ERR_INVALID_NAME_SIZE)
  private String firstName;

  @Pattern(regexp = "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9]+([ a-zA-Z0-9,'.?!\\-_&]+)*$", message = ValidationConstant.ERR_INVALID_COMMENT)
  @Size(max = 200, message = ValidationConstant.ERR_INVALID_COMMENT_SIZE)
  private String comment;

}
```

When this validation is called, at times the CPU usage of the thread shows 100%.(It works most of the time).
The thread dump shows that thread is stuck in Pattern class.

```
"http-nio-8080-exec-4" #53 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fce45f0d000 nid=0x44 runnable [0x00007fcdb3af6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$5.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5265)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$5.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5265)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$5.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5265)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3790)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4274)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.matchInit(Pattern.java:4818)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Prolog.match(Pattern.java:4755)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Begin.match(Pattern.java:3539)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.match(Matcher.java:1270)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.matches(Matcher.java:604)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.PatternValidator.isValid(PatternValidator.java:60)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.PatternValidator.isValid(PatternValidator.java:24)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:171)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(SimpleConstraintTree.java:68)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.doValidateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:120)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:533)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:496)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:465)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:430)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:380)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedAnnotatedObjectForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:605)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:568)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:389)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:169)
```

Is there any issue in my regex?

The regex for first name validation which supports alphabets and few special chars `^([a-zA-Z])+[-.'\\s]?[-a-zA-Z]*$`

Regex for message box text `^[\sa-zA-Z0-9]+([ a-zA-Z0-9,'.?!\-_&]+)*$`

Comment: Hibernate and Spring use the same validation so yes it occurs in both because it is the same. The problem is your RegExp not the validators nor Spring or Hibernate.

Comment: You just added another regex, but it will be complicated to handle a moving target here. Also for testing I would recommend that you focus on one problem / regex at a time - can you maybe set up a test for you that handles them individually? And if the first regex works but not the second, ask another question for that (with a reference to this question). If the first still makes troubles, of course you are welcome to add clarifying details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually use the first group? `([a-zA-Z])`

I don't think so, because otherwise you would have found out that it does not get filled with the letters up to the first non-letter character.

You probably want to put the `+` sign into the group:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+)[-.'\\s]?[-a-zA-Z]*$
```

or do not use a group at all, if you don't need that part as group (I think that it is probably not used in your annotation):

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[-.'\\s]?[-a-zA-Z]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

The effect of repetitions in the form of backtracking makes regex unexpectedly costly.

In this case an optional interpunction between letters may take long, as in the empty case it might happen at any position.

Instead of

```
"^[a-zA-Z]+[-.'\\s]?[-a-zA-Z]*$"
```

try

```
"^[a-zA-Z]+([-.'\\s][-a-zA-Z]*)?$"
```

This will enter the part starting with interpunction only when there is a match.

In general do a microbenchmark (with a benchmark library), as things might not be so clear.

However regex will remain costly.